# Bootstrap 3 css, centering element containing media classes

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, media

Centering an element is normally done with the style="display:block;margin:0 auto" or in bootstrap 3 by simply using the **center-block** class, but somehow this cant be done if you want to center elements containing media class,
ie :

```
<div class="media">
    <div class="center-block">
        <div class="media-left"><img class="media-object" src="..."></div>
        <div class="media-body">
            <h4 class="media-heading">Header</h4>
            <h5>Info</h5>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

if I use the **text-center** class instead, only the media-body gets centered and the media-left element stays solidly in the same place

Answer (score 0):

center-block only center the block element so you need to used particular block to used. To center text you have to used as you say text-center. I just create a sample here. Just check it an send us your feedback.

Demo - http://goo.gl/QrgSE1

Comment: hey Nithin, this particular code has the text below the image, while media-left and media-body supposed to have the image on the left side and the text directly to its right, anyway to fix it ?

Comment: Hey.. I did new demo for you. If you want something more let me know. Demo - http://goo.gl/mS90oR

Answer (score 0):

While i have not found a way to do it using media bootstrap css, there is a simple way:

```
<div align = 'center'>
  <img style="vertical-align:middle" src="https://placehold.it/60x60">
  <span style="">Works.</span>
</div>
```

Here is a demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/tj2qx659/